# cl.exe release or debug

Tags: c++, visual-c++

We're using VC++ 2015 with gmake. How does does that compiler determine whether it's a Release or Debug build?

cl.exe  /nologo /Zc:wchar_t /wd4675 /wd4407 /wd4595 /W3 /FS /GR /GS- /EHac /Zc:threadSafeInit- /X /WX /Zi /Ob1 /Oi /Ot  /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "UNICODE" /D "_UNICODE" /D _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

The main reason for this is to find out which value cl.exe uses for _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL and adjust it accordingly.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: The Debug configuration changes several compile options.  /Od to disable all optimization is the most obvious one, /RTC is particularly helpful to diagnose UB.  /ZI supports edit+continue.  _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL is a macro that needs to be specified with /D.  What you showed is wonky, it has Release-like options but does not define NDEBUG.  That tends to happens with makefiles.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the setting by running the strings utility on the *.pdb files.

Comment: So what is the setting?  Please edit this comment with the answer for future readers.

Comment: _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0. It seems that our build is in Release mode